# Parse cloud function - code ot executed in sequence

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk, parse-cloud-code

I have below function to update rows if meeting some condition and at the end of for loop, response include how many rows updated.Despite more than zero rows updated, response shows zero. Looking at log, it seems reponse.success() fires before completing for loop.

why so?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("reset", function(request, response) {


    var isSaveNeeded = false
  var Query = new Parse.Query("price");
  Query.equalTo('isActive', true);
  Query.find({useMasterKey:true})
      .then((results) => {
        console.log("Found " + results.length + " price rows")
        var currentDate = moment()
        var noOfRowsUpdated = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
            var valid_till_date = results[i].get('valid_till_date');

            if (valid_till_date == null) {
                // if user had not selected valid_till_date then set to expire after system max no of days
                var updatedAt = results[i].get('updatedAt');
                if (currentDate.diff(updatedAt,'days') > 10) {
                  console.log("Permanent change row to be set inactive. Updated at - " + currentDate.diff(updatedAt)+ updatedAt)
                    results[i].set('isActive',false)
                    isSaveNeeded = true
                }
            } else if (currentDate.diff(valid_till_date) > 0) {
                // check whether valid_till_date has passed
                console.log("Found row with elapsed valid date "  + results[i].id)
                results[i].set("isActive",false)
                isSaveNeeded = true
            }
            if (isSaveNeeded == true) {
              console.log("Record needs to be saved for " + results[i].id)
              results[i].save(null, {useMasterKey:true})
                .then(function (user) {
                    ++noOfRowsUpdated
                    console.log("reset : Object ID: " + results[i].id + " saved - " + noOfRowsUpdated)
                  })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("reset : Error saving Object ID: " + results[i].id + error);
                    response.error(error);
                })
            } else {

              console.log("Record not to be saved for " + results[i].id)
            }
            isSaveNeeded = false
        } // end of for loop
        //BELOW IS EXECUTED BEFORE FOR LOOP COMPLETES
        console.log("Updated " + noOfRowsUpdated +" price rows");
        response.success("Updated " + noOfRowsUpdated +" price rows")
      }) // end of .then((results) 
      .catch(function(error) {
        response.error("Failed to fetch from price" + error );
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.com's `save` runs async, so that loop finishes before the saves happen.  The solution is to reorganize the code a little bit, and wait for the saves to happen before executing the response functions.

The trick is to collect the promises returned by each save in an array and wait for the fulfillment of those promises with `Promise.when()` (synonym for Promise.all())

To make it clearer, factor out the "is save needed" logic, so this cloud function can be only about handling the database...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("reset", function(request, response) {
    var Query = new Parse.Query("price");
    Query.equalTo('isActive', true);
    Query.find({useMasterKey:true}).then((results) => {
        console.log("Found " + results.length + " price rows");
        // assuming ES6 or something like underscore
        let pricesToSave = results.filter(price => priceNeedsSave(price));

        // here's the important part, collect the promise from each save
        // proceed only after the promises have completed
        let promises =  pricesToSave.map(price => price.save(null, {useMasterKey:true}));
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(() => pricesToSave.length);
    }).then(count => {
        response.success("Updated " + count +" price rows");
    }).catch(error => {
        response.error("Failed to fetch from price" + error );
    });
}
```

Just for completeness, below is the factored-out needsSave logic.  (OP should check this over, I just copied the body of the loop)...

```
function priceNeedsSave(price) {
    var isSaveNeeded = false;
    var currentDate = moment()

    var valid_till_date = price.get('valid_till_date');
    if (valid_till_date == null) {
        // if user had not selected valid_till_date then set to expire after system max no of days
        var updatedAt = price.get('updatedAt');
        if (currentDate.diff(updatedAt,'days') > 10) {
          console.log("Permanent change row to be set inactive. Updated at - " + currentDate.diff(updatedAt)+ updatedAt)
            price.set('isActive',false)
            isSaveNeeded = true
        }
    } else if (currentDate.diff(valid_till_date) > 0) {
        // check whether valid_till_date has passed
        console.log("Found row with elapsed valid date "  + price.id)
        price.set("isActive",false)
        isSaveNeeded = true
    }
    return isSaveNeeded;
}
```

Comment: I was suspecting async but wasn't aware how to handle in javascript code. I must say this 'Promise' concept is taking more time to master than thought!! Will try your code but have a question - is correct that "results.filter(price =>" pass one Parse object at a time to function? if so then  for loop isn't needed right?

Comment: @ashishn, also note that Parse.Object implements dirty(), so an alternative would be to just change the price object in that function and filter on price.dirty().

Comment: Here's some tips about promises. While Parse has it's own Parse.Promise class, they're "backbone" style, and compatible with other backbone style promises, which near every API with server calls will use.  When you add a callback using `.then()` or `.always()`, etc, the result of that gets passed down the chain of promises.  If it is already wrapped in a promise, it will call the next success or error handler, as appropriate. If it is not, it automatically gets wrapped in a resolved promise.  If there is no return, as soon as the end of the block is reached, an empty resolved promise

Comment: gets returned, even if there is asynchronous code running still that does have a return value.  Make sure if you call an asynchronous method inside another, you use a return statement to wait for and return the results of the nested promise.  Also, if you fail a promise, and your `.then()`s only have success handlers, the error gets passed all the way down the chain to the next error handler.  Also note that once an error handler works the same way - it will return its value and pass it along. If you don't return a value, it returns an empty resolved promise! This threw me off hard.

Comment: Be careful with that latter issue, as it can cause unexpected behavior where you think you're catching an error but the function returns success, or crashes because the next link in the chain's success handler expected a value that didn't get passed, because it got the empty resolved promise from an error handler. Make sure you "break" your chain appropriately, or, even better, only have a single error handler on your outer chain so any failed promises will always get passed all the way down.

Comment: @danh Thank you for the code. It worked after i removed couple of errors. have edited the functions to correct it.

Comment: @jake-t Thank you for the tip. Will remember this. Appreciate.